# Recreational math

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Where can I post problems and solutions with no commitment to formal mathematics?

Some of the problems I do I do not find equal on the internet, like some variants of sacks spiral, problems of counting involving geometry or circular sequences as in the collatz conjecture, they apparently have no good application. How do I judge if they are interesting enough to be posted somewhere as recreational math?

If this is not the right place for this question, please tell me where to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to post puzzles for other people to solve, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com is where you should do so.

If you want to know the underlying maths behind a problem then MSE is the place, but you must ask quite a specific question and not just say "Explain this please."

Comment: In fact, I would just like to understand when things are interesting enough to be discussed.
Explain to me for example why the sacks spiral is interesting, I created some variations that also have patterns that you can extract equations from. Where could I publish them?

Comment: The issue here is that MSE is not a discussion site: it is where people come to have their maths problem solved. However interesting your puzzles are, this is not the place for them. There are puzzling sites available if you use Google. If I were you I'd have a look at the puzzling stackexchange site to see what sort of puzzles they like. Looking at the available tags should help.

Answer (score 5):

Math.se has a tag `recreational-mathematics`.  See [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-mathematics) for the 4,000 questions with that tag.  Perhaps looking at those, in particular the ones that were upvoted and answered, will give you some idea about what is acceptable in math.se.

Let me repeat what Peter said;  math.se is not a discussion site, and it is not an opinion site.